Why am I not receiving categories using MoECardHelper.getCardCategories() in MoEngage Self-Handled Cards?
I am integrating the MoEngage Self-Handled Cards feature in my Android application. To fetch the available cards categories, I am using the following method:
val sdkInstance = SdkInstanceManager.defaultInstance ?: throw IllegalStateException("Either pass instance Id or initialise default Instance")
val categories = MoECardHelper.getCardCategories(context, sdkInstance.instanceMeta.instanceId)

However, the method is returning an empty list.
Questions:
How Are there any additional configurations required on the MoEngage Dashboard to add or manage categories for self-handled cards? If yes please provide step to add categories in MoEngage.
As per the documentation, there should be an option to select card categories while creating a card campaign. However, when I navigate to create a card campaign, this option is missing.
Here’s a screenshot of my current dashboard view and the documentation link for reference:
Document Screenshot: 
MoEngage Dashboard Screenshot: 
If this requires enabling specific settings or features, could you point me in the right direction? Any insights or steps to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You can add your card categories by contacting MoEngage Support Team.
https://help.moengage.com/hc/en-us/articles/19708702327572-Raise-a-Support-Ticket-Through-MoEngage-Dashboard
